# How to extend FormControl functionality via prototype?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want all objects of the `FormControl` type to have the observable (or event emitter) field (e.g. `onMarkAsDirty`) which will be triggered on `markAsDirty` method call. I tried to implement this by extending `FormControl` prototype, but it is too hard for me. Can you help me please and write some sketches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extends a class is easy. You has the code of the FormControl (Really of AbstractControl) in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8cef5dd7c1c79f503671f2f196c754ce307a8a3b/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts)

So you can define

```
export class FormControlExtends extends FormControl {
  markAsDirty(opts: { onlySelf?: boolean } = {}): void {
    (this as { pristine: boolean }).pristine = false;
    
    if (this['_parent'] && !opts.onlySelf) {
      this['_parent'].markAsDirty(opts);
    }
    //make some more
    console.log('say hello');
  }
}
```

See that to access to a private variable (in this case "_parent") use square bracket, e.g. not this._parent else this['_parent']

And you can use as

```
control=new FormControlExtends(null)
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqfqcn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-control-extends.ts)